# Program that opens AND closes other programs automatically

Tags: automation, productivity

Is there a program that can open and close another program on a schedule?

I am trying to limit the frequency at which I check and respond to email/slack/etc. And I have it all in a firefox browser window. What I would like to do is have it open for 15 minutes every 1 hour.

Comment: How about `cron` to open Firefox every hour and another `cron` entry to run a bash script that kills Firefox 15 minutes after the hour?

Comment: I'm looking for something a little more aware. ie, if I'm using it, it stays open. I like this idea though because it's easy to implement.

Comment: Someone good at bash could probably write a script to check if Firefox is already running and start Firefox if not. The same script should record the pid of the new instance of Firefox if started, and pass it on to second script 15 minutes later. If no pid is recorded, the second script won't kill anything.

Comment: I guess manually closing it when I'm done isn't such a terrible option either. So then we only need to reopen on a schedule.